# github - how to clone via ssh?

Tags: git, github, ssh, clone

In the past I've been able to get an ssh link to clone from guthub using the dropdown link menu. However, the only option I see now is for a http link. Hown can I generate an ssh link I can use with `git clone`?

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in, i mean in your account to be able to use your ssh keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up an SSH key with Github? If you have, try the following:

`git@github.com:$USER_NAME/$REPO_NAME.git`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't logged in. The ssh option appears after I'm logged in.